# cast any pointer to char poiner using static_cast

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, strict-aliasing

If according to strict aliasing rule char pointer may point to any type pointer, then why can't I cast any-type pointer to char pointer using static_cast?

```
char *ptr;
int *intPtr;

ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(intPtr); // ok
ptr = static_cast<char*>(intPtr); // error: invalid static_cast from type 'int*' to type 'char*'
```

Comment: See [What good is static_cast?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#static-cast)

Answer (score 7):

How `static_cast` works is unrelated to the strict aliasing rule.

`static_cast` will not allow you to cast between arbitrary pointer types, it can only be used to cast to<sup>1</sup> and from<sup>2</sup> `void*` (and casting to `void*` is usually superfluous as the conversion is already implicit<sup>3</sup>).

You could do this

```
ptr = static_cast<char*>(static_cast<void*>(intPtr));
```

but there is absolutely no difference<sup>4</sup> between that and

```
ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>(intPtr);
```

---

https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf

<sup>1</sup>[expr.static.cast] / 6

<sup>2</sup>[expr.static.cast] / 13

<sup>3</sup>[conv.ptr] / 2

<sup>4</sup>[expr.reinterpret.cast] / 7

Comment: link you are referring to requires authorization

Comment: @ignorant That's odd, it was available earlier. Added a different link.

Comment: @user657267 To say that `static_cast<>` "can only be used to cast to and from `void*`" without qualification is very misleading - it can do a lot more than that!

Comment: @AAT Thank you captain obvious, please read that phrase in the context of the first half of the sentence.

Comment: @user657267 Rudeness will get you precisely nowhere. Goodbye.